# How can I manually perform refetch on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In my application, I use `react-query` to handle fetching data. I use `useQuery` to receive data in my components. The code for this is shown below:

```
   const { isLoading, data} = useQuery('albums', fetchAlbums)

   const fetchAlbums = () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/albums')
      return res.data
   }

   return (
      isLoading ? <Spinner /> :
      <div>
         // When clicking this button, check if there is new data from the api endpoint, and if so, set data variable to the new data
         <button>Refetch data</button>

         // Display the data
         {data}
      </div>
   )
```

The code above works fine, however when the button displayed is clicked, it should check if there is new data from the `endpoint` specified in `fetchAlbums` and **if there is new data** from the endpoint, update the `data` variable for `albums` and display the new data. The issue I have is that I want the old `data` to still be displayed whilst the `refetch` occurs (i.e after the button is clicked), and if there is new data, **then** replace the old `data` displayed with the new data. How could I potentially accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: If what you ultimately want is to see the old data before the new data is shown, you can use the remove the spinner or make it only work when there is no `data`

Comment: @Odri Could you please explain what you mean by this, as I don't quite understand the proposed solution

Answer (score 4):

By default, useQuery fetches immediately when the component calling it mounts, but not everyone wants this behaviour.

### Method 1: Enabled Boolean

You’re able to set the default behaviour to NOT fetch data immediately using a key enabled and setting it to false

```
  const { data } = useQuery("comments", fetchComments, {
    enabled: false
  });
```

If we want to use a button to trigger this we can maintain a piece of state that holds true or false and then pass the setEnabled method to a button.

On click, the query will fetch the data.

```
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
const { data } = useQuery("comments", fetchComments, {
    enabled: enabled
  });
<button onClick={() => setEnabled(true)}>Some Button</button>
```

### Method 2: Refetch()

My preferred method is to use refetch . This is a method that comes with useQuery and is closer to the functionality many of us are looking for in this scenario.

The data is not fetched automatically. We have turned it off using enabled: false.

We can then pass the refetch method to our button to grab the data on demand without toggling any state.

```
export const useComments = () => {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery("comments", fetchComments, {
    enabled: false
  });
<button onClick={() => refetch()}>Some Button</button>
```

Comment: @HerandoAbella In regards to **method 2**, could I set `enabled: true` if I also wanted automatic refetch as well as manually refetching after clicking a button? Or are there any problems with this solution?

Comment: Also when calling `refetch()`, does this still go to cache first, or immediately make a fresh API call to the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you would look to do is to [call `invalidateQueries()`](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation) to invalidate the query, and then on next render of the component your call to `useQuery()` should refetch the data from the server instead of getting the data from cache.

Comment: So after clicking the button, call `invalidateQueries()`. The button should subsequently cause a re-render of the component meaning `useQuery` would perform a fresh call right? However, due to a `re-render` of the component occuring after clicking the button, my component would return a `loading` indicator in place of `data` and not the `old data` like I require.

Comment: The desired outcome is after clicking the button, still show the old `data`, not a `loading` spinner or anything else, and then **if there is new data from the relevant endpoint**, replace the old `data` with the new updated data